# Taking table tag instead div

Tags: javascript

I wrote a json code in javascript . But its taking div tag ( class : demir ) . I want to take table tag (class: demirlist) Which Part of my code have to change? I will be grateful if you can help me . In addition, the command that can be drawn is as follows.

code :

```
function rmvdemir(a) {
  demir=$("input[name=demirjson]").data("demir");
  demir[a]["sil"]=1;
  console.log("aaaa");
  $("input[name=demirjson]").data("demir",demir);
  $("input[name=demirjson]").val(JSON.stringify(demir));
  drawTable(demir);
}

function editLoad() {
  if ($("#isedit").data("edit")) {
    demir=$.parseJSON($("input[name=demirjson]").val());
    $("input[name=demirjson]").data("demir",demir);
    $("input[name=demirjson]").val(JSON.stringify(demir));
    drawTable(demir);
  }
}

$("#demircapekle").on("click",function functionName() {

  demir=$("input[name=demirjson]").data("demir");
  if (typeof(demir)!='object') {
    demir={};
  }
  id=$("#id").val();
  cap=$("#cap").val();
  adet=$("#adet").val();
  boy=$("#boy").val();
  console.log(cap);
  console.log(adet);
  console.log(boy);
  if (cap>0) {
    $("#demirlist").html();
      abc={id:id,cap:cap,adet:adet,boy:boy,sil:0};
      demir[id+"-"+cap]=(abc);
    $("input[name=demirjson]").data("demir",demir);
    $("input[name=demirjson]").val(JSON.stringify(demir));
  drawTable(demir);
   $("#id").val("");
   $("#cap").val("");
   $("#adet").val("");
   $("#boy").val("");
}
```

drawTable :

```
function drawTable(demir) {

   $("#demirlist").html("<tr><td>Demir Çapı</td><td>Adet</td><td>Boy</td><td>Sil</td></tr>");
   console.log(demir);
  for (var a in demir) {
    if (demir[a]["sil"]==0) {
      if (demir[a]["id"]>0) {
        $(".demir").append("<tr><td>"+demir[a]["cap"]+"</td><td>"+demir[a]["adet"]+"</td><td>"+demir[a]["boy"]+"</td><td><a class='btn btn-warning btn-xs il' target='_blank'>Düzenle</a>  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('"+a+"')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      }else{
        $(".demir").append("<tr><td>"+demir[a]["cap"]+"</td><td>"+demir[a]["adet"]+"</td><td>"+demir[a]["boy"]+"</td><td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('"+a+"')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that "takes the div", which I expect is `drawTable`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey is it ?

Comment: Looks like it's appending the headers to `#demirlist`, but adding the rows to `.demir`. If you want them appended to the same place, use the same selector, `#demirlist`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry, which ones ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `drawTable` function:

```js
function drawTable(demir) {
  // here, the code sets the HTML of the element with the id "demirlist" to a table row.
  $("#demirlist").html("<tr><td>Demir Çapı</td><td>Adet</td><td>Boy</td><td>Sil</td></tr>");
  console.log(demir);
  for (var a in demir) {
    if (demir[a]["sil"] == 0) {
      if (demir[a]["id"] > 0) {
        // here, the code appends a table row to an element with the class "demir"
        $(".demir").append("<tr><td>" + demir[a]["cap"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["adet"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["boy"] + "</td><td><a class='btn btn-warning btn-xs il' target='_blank'>Düzenle</a>  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('" + a + "')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      } else {
        // here, the code appends a table row to an element with the class "demir"
        $(".demir").append("<tr><td>" + demir[a]["cap"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["adet"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["boy"] + "</td><td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('" + a + "')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You start off by setting the HTML of an element with an id of "demirlist" to a table row. Then, in the loop, you append table rows to an element with a *class* of "demir", which may or may not be the same element. To make sure they all get appended to the same element, just use the same selector in all cases:

```js
function drawTable(demir) {
  // here, the code sets the HTML of the element with the id "demirlist" to a table row.
  $("#demirlist").html("<tr><td>Demir Çapı</td><td>Adet</td><td>Boy</td><td>Sil</td></tr>");
  console.log(demir);
  for (var a in demir) {
    if (demir[a]["sil"] == 0) {
      if (demir[a]["id"] > 0) {
        // Changed this to the same selector as the one that got the first row
        $("#demirlist").append("<tr><td>" + demir[a]["cap"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["adet"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["boy"] + "</td><td><a class='btn btn-warning btn-xs il' target='_blank'>Düzenle</a>  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('" + a + "')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      } else {
        // Changed this to the same selector as the one that got the first row
        $("#demirlist").append("<tr><td>" + demir[a]["cap"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["adet"] + "</td><td>" + demir[a]["boy"] + "</td><td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs il' onclick=rmvdemir('" + a + "')>Sil</button></td></tr>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```